# AngularJS Reactive Images (ng-class)

Tags: angularjs, onclick, ng-class, onhover

I have 3 variations of 1 image.  I need to swap the image based on its Event State  For Example: 'current' 'onClick' 'onHover'.  Want to use standard Windows Events.  Can I use Angular's 'ng-class' with IMAGES and add in `onClick` & `onCover` as my Javascript test expression?  Precisely testing for the Event Listener ?!

for example:

This is a requirement from my customer.  Is it possible with AngularJS.

Comment: For Example:  here's the code I would like to get running.  When the user interacts with the image the presentation of the button changes based on it's watch list state.   <img src="img.png" class="currentImgStyling" ng-class="{'clickedImgStyling':onClick, 'hoverImgStyling':inHover }"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a short but worthy blog post about this issue [here](http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2015/01/change-image-source-on-mouseover-using.html#.VUBhKRPF-UA).

It suggests using a strategy similar to the following for mouseover/hover events...

```
<div id="divID" ng-init="imgsrc='/images/twitter_blue.png'" ng-mouseover="imgsrc='/images/twitter_brown.png'" ng-mouseout="imgsrc='/images/twitter_blue.png'">
    <img ng-src="{{imgsrc}}"/>
    <div>Image description</div>
</div>
```

Additionally, you could use `ng-click` to manage changes in `ng-src` for click events

```
<div id="divID" ng-click="updateImageSrc()" ...
```

Comment: excellent.  the "short but worthy blog post" has the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* AngularJS makes UX pretty nice! */

    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <div id="explorer" 
     ng-init="imgsrc='https:///idle.png'" 
ng-mouseover="imgsrc='https:///hover.png'" 
    ng-click="imgsrc='https:///current.png'">
        <img ng-src="{{imgsrc}}" />
        <div>Explore</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```